# lvalue error when trying to sort linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, lvalue

I wanted the program to rearrange a linked list from smallest to greatest but i keep on getting "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment" when i try to make `prev->link()=temp;` and `minum->link()=head_ptr;`

```
  node* previouse_minimum(node*& head_ptr){
    node* cursor;
    node* minimum;
    node* prev;
    minimum=head_ptr;

    for(cursor=head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor=cursor->link())
      if(cursor->data() < minimum->data())
         minimum=cursor;

    cursor = head_ptr;
    prev = cursor;
   while(cursor->link() != minimum)
    {
      cursor = cursor->link();
      prev = cursor;

    }
    cout << prev->link()->data() << endl;
    return prev;

}

void sort(node*& head_ptr, node*& marker_ptr)
{
   node* print_ptr;
   node* prev = previouse_minimum(head_ptr);
   node* temp=NULL;
   node* minum;
   marker_ptr = head_ptr;

   while(marker_ptr->link()->link()!= NULL)
    {
      minum = prev->link();
      temp=minum->link();
      prev->link()=temp;
      minum->link()=head_ptr;
      head_ptr=minum;
      marker_ptr=minum->link();
      prev=previouse_minimum(marker_ptr);
    }
   for(print_ptr = head_ptr; print_ptr !=NULL; print_ptr = print_ptr->link())
   cout <<  print_ptr->data() << " ";

   cout << endl;

   }
```

Comment: Clearly `link()` is a method returning a lvalue, which means you can't assign anything to it. You don't show your code for `node`, but you should use the underlying variables for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

`prev->link()` as well as `minum->link()` are functions that return a node. You can't assign a value/pointer to functions. To set the nodes, you could overload the `link()` function with an argument like `void link(node* input)`.